# Click photo slideshow

Tags: html, ajax

I am trying to make my photos appear in sequence when I click each one of them.
When I click the first image it goes to the second, but I don't get the same for the third.

The code at the main page:

```
<script>
function loadXMLDoc()
{
var xmlhttp;
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
  xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
else
  {// code for IE6, IE5
  xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
  {
  if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
    {
    document.getElementById("myDiv").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
    }
  }
xmlhttp.open("GET","ajax_info.html",true);
xmlhttp.send();
}
</script>



<div id="myDiv">

<h2><a><button type="submit" onclick="loadXMLDoc()"><img src="/project2_ver3/vor/pic5.jpg" alt="vor" width="540" height="418"/></a></button></h2>

</div>
```

Then the code at **ajax_info.html**:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<script>
function loadXMLDoc2()
{
var xmlhttp;
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
  xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
else
  {// code for IE6, IE5
  xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
  {
  if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
    {
    document.getElementById("myDivv").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
    }
  }
xmlhttp.open("GET","\project2_ver3\ajax_infoo.html",true);
xmlhttp.send();
}
</script>



<div id="myDivv">

<h2><button type="submit" onclick="loadXMLDoc2()"><img src="/project2_ver3/vor/pic2.jpg" alt="vor" width="540" height="418"/></button></h2>

</div>




</body>
</html>
```

And finally, the code at **ajax_infoo.html**:

(code trimmed):

```
xmlhttp.open("GET","ajax_infooo.html",true);
xmlhttp.send();
}
</script>
<div id="myDiv">
<h2><button type="submit" onclick="loadXMLDoc2()"><img src="/project2_ver3/vor/pic1.jpg" alt="vor" width="540" height="418"/></button></h2>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Come on guys ! Anyone ? I burnt my mind with that !

Comment: Please see answer to similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5628108/simplest-ajax-photo-gallery

Comment: Any reason you can't use a common library like JQuery to handle all these little details?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11694977/setting-innerhtml-with-a-script-inside http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2592092/executing-script-elements-inserted-with-innerhtml

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are replacing the complete "myDiv" innerHTML. Doing this will deactivate the onclick function you wrote for the button.
Try addressing that problem. That should solve it.